# How can I get involved socially whilst travelling without necessarily having a job?

Tags: working-holiday, socializing, volunteering

I want to take 6 months off, anywhere in the world at the moment. I'm a social person, I love nature/away from big cities. But I also want to work on my own IT project, whilst not necessarily working (don't need the money). But the problem is I want to be participate in things with people and have social groups (the things that come naturally with bar work, backpacker work, etc.)!

I'm terrible at imagining scenarios, I'm looking for recommendations on how I can be social active, whilst pursuing my own project, I'm open for:

1. Doing some 1/2 days a week max (work is fine, or volunteer stuff etc)
2. Anything! :-)

Would love to hear some imaginative ideas!

Locations of interest are anywhere really, but in particular: Tropical islands, anywhere in Europe (have a passport), etc.

Answer (score 9):

I've moved countries a lot, doing contracts.  One of the finest resources that I've found is [meetup.com](http://www.meetup.com/find/)

[image]

You sign up, give your city, and your interests, and it starts suggesting social groups and events for you! I've used it to meet people and try new things when I lived in Vancouver, and now here in Melbourne, Australia.

We can't tell you what to do or where to go - that's subjective and polling, and far too open ended.  But hopefully this will show you HOW to find these things.

Comment: Assuming you move to a city where meetup is popular - it does seem to vary a lot around the world!